# CSS Image Resizing for subreddit theme

Tags: css, image, resize, aspect-ratio, reddit

I am currently trying to use a subreddit theme and resize an image to be bigger/actual size of uploaded image.

Current code for the Logo is:

```
/* SUBEDDIT LOGO ADDON
----------------------*/
#header .pagename a {
width: 100px;
background: url(%%subredditlogo%%) left center/auto 50px  
}
```

I am trying to scale image to be bigger with keeping aspect ratio.

Like I said this is on Reddit, so I can only interact with the subreddit stylesheet.

---

I have edited it some and played with it, I have gotten improvements, but not the full image to show.

Here is my current code:

```
/* SUBEDDIT LOGO ADDON
----------------------*/
#header .pagename a {
width: 300px;
background: url(%%subredditlogo%%) left center/auto 300px;
background-size:100% 200%;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

It has resized the width but I cant get the height to change. I have tired the:

```
left center/auto 300px;
```

but nothing, and also the

```
height: 100%;
height: auto;
```

Just looking to get it fixed now.

Comment: Have you tried background-size:cover?

Comment: yes, doesnt seem to do the job, how would you try it?

Comment: Posted an answer.. hope that it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
background-image: url(%%subredditlogo%%);
background-position: left center;
background-size:cover;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

I believe you need to break out your "background" css into individual attributes in order for each attribute to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
#header .pagename a img{
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
}
```

Try this for auto resize img.

Comment: the logo disappears.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
  background: url(logopath) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
```